# What is a Cursive Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Cursive Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Cursive Words™ | Not Cursive Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BILLIONS | TRILLIONS |
| CIRCUMCISION | VASECTOMY |
| LOLLIPOPS | SUCKERS |
| MICROSCOPIC | MACROSCOPIC |
| PLUG | OUTLET |
| POISONOUS | VENOMOUS |
| RUNNING | SPRINTING |
| SUBDIVISION | NEIGHBORHOOD |
| SUSPICIOUS | TRUSTING |
| SWIMMING | FLOATING |
| UNCOMPROMISING | FLEXIBLE |
| UNCONSCIOUS | ALERT |
| VOODOO | MAGIC |
| WINDMILL | PROPELLOR |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Cursive Words™,Not Cursive Words™
BILLIONS,TRILLIONS
CIRCUMCISION,VASECTOMY
LOLLIPOPS,SUCKERS
MICROSCOPIC,MACROSCOPIC
PLUG,OUTLET
POISONOUS,VENOMOUS
RUNNING,SPRINTING
SUBDIVISION,NEIGHBORHOOD
SUSPICIOUS,TRUSTING
SWIMMING,FLOATING
UNCOMPROMISING,FLEXIBLE
UNCONSCIOUS,ALERT
VOODOO,MAGIC
WINDMILL,PROPELLOR
```

Comment: The cursive words lack the letters `AEFHJKQTXYZ`, of which I think `AEFHT` are significant. I'd like to say that cursive words are those that can be written in a single stroke in cursive, with two-stroke letters like `TFX` being obstacles, but it's not matching up with my US-trained writing and [online examples](http://cdn.rainbowresource.netdna-cdn.com/products/041464.jpg). For example, I'd write MAGIC in caps in a single stroke. Can I check that this isn't the right thing with you just writing differently than I do?

Comment: @xnor Cursive Words™ are font-dependent and so the examples shown apply exactly as written. The name should not be taken so literally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Cursive Word is a word which, in that font...

> ...only needs one stroke per letter to be written. That is, no letters have more than 2 intersections with an odd number of paths coming from them ("intersections" includes endpoints)

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that a cursive word can be written entirely in one stroke in cursive.

Comment: @JoeZ.: That's incorrect. Many Cursive Words contain the letter "i", which cannot be written in one stroke.

Comment: You're right, I totally didn't notice there were "i"s in the cursive words. >_>